# Polynomial divisibility is unchanged by coeff. field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I would like to verify the validity of the following line of thought:

Let $K \subset E$ be a field extension. Let $K[x]$ be the polynomial ring
over $x$ and denote $K(x)$ its field of quotients (the rational functions over $K$).

Now assume $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $f(x),g(x) \in K[x]$ and $h(x) \in E[x]$ and all $f$, $g$, $h$ are different than zero.
Then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = h(x)$ in $E(x)$. So $h(x) \in K(x)$. But $h(x)$ is a polynomial, so $h(x) \in K[x]$.

Is there any other simpler argument than that?

Added:

Let me be more specific. Let $x^p - a \in K[x]$, with $p$ being prime and $char(K)=p$. Let $b$ be the unique root of $x^p - a$ in its splitting field $K(b)$. Then $x^p - a=(x-b)^p \in K(b)[x].$ Let $m_b(x) \in K[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $K$. Then $m_b(x)$ divides $(x-b)^p$ and so $m_b(x)=(x-b)^l$ and $l$ is the smallest positive integer for which $(x-b)^l \in K[x]$. Let $p = lq+r$ where $0 \ge <l$. Then $x^p-a=(m_b(x))^q (x-b)^r$. Can i conclude that $(x-b)^r \in K[x]$ and so $r=0$ by the minimality of $l$?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have shown elsewhere that $K(x)\cap E[x]=K[x]$ (you can form the intersection inside $E(x)$), then this is ok.

Comment: i see, that's a subtle point

Comment: @Jyrki: i added a specific instance of my question. What do you think in that case?

Comment: @Manos Have you tried somehow to prove that $f\mid g$ in $E[X]$ $\implies$ $f\mid g$ in $K[X]$? (In my opinion it's not clear at all what you want to prove.)

Comment: @user26857: Hi :) Thanks for you comment. But this is such an old question that i don't even remembe what i wanted to prove.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ It follows from the *uniqueness* of the quotient (and remainder) in the division algorithm (which is the same in $\,K[x]\,$ and $\,E[x],\,$ using the polynomial degree as the Euclidean valuation). Thus since dividing $\,f\,$ by $\,g\,$ in $\,E[x]\,$ leaves remainder $0$, by uniqueness, the remainder must also be $\,0\,$ in $\,K[x]\,,\,$ i.e. $\,g\ |\ f\ $ in $\,E[x]\,$ $\Rightarrow\, g\ |\ f\ $ in $\,K[x].\,$

This is but one of [many examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com+dubuque++%22uniqueness+theorems%22+proving+equalities) of the *power of uniqueness theorems for proving equalities*.

Comment: This is very good. Thanks a lot.